# Hide html5 elements from view source

Tags: html

I have html tags that render some data. Such components are rendered conditionally else are not visible. In view source, anyone can still see the data entered in the html component. How can I skip the html component from view source along with its data.?
Just to mention, I cannot disable view source button.

Comment: Delete them from source code.

Comment: can't you use server side programming to push html or data to your page?

Comment: @Jurik Sry, didnt get you..How do you mean.

Comment: @RanchiRhino, Nah, as it is existing code and doing such thing will need huge efforts. Any attribute that can help me with this?

Comment: Like @RanchiRhino wrote - use a server language, just send the data you need to show.

Comment: If you would provide an example, we maybe could say you more.

Comment: complexity may be in architecture of application, but codewise it is as simple as creating a container say <div class = "mycon> then `document.getElementById("mycon").text= "your data here"`

Comment: Use AngularJS to redesign your entire application in views and use angular routes and template feature to break down your html code in separate files, and then compile everything into js file.
Here's a plunker https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/toh-5/ts/plnkr.html demonstrating same.